# Archiving the Jenkins build log

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to archive the build log of every build, e.g. to a database. I know how to archive artifacts, but I don't see anything obvious for the build log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need that your job would end before you archive it. 
following is a groovy script with different methods to get the console log of a build. the script can be run from a another job using groovy step or scripptler step.

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)
def bld = job.getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)
//use the method that suits you
bld.getLog(100) //number of lines to read
bld.getLogFile()
bld.getLogReader()
```